# Call object of Static Inner Class

Tags: java

I'm trying to call an object from a static member class, but I get an exceptionInitializationError. Please could you look at my code and let me know what's wrong?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class StaticInit {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



    ArrayList<Olive> olives = OliveJar.olives;

 for( Olive o : olives) {
     System.out.println(o);
 }

    }

public static class OliveJar {
        public static ArrayList<Olive> olives;

         static {
            olives.add(new Olive("Olive 1!", 10));
            olives.add(new Olive("Olive 2!", 30));
            olives.add(new Olive("Olive 3", 10));
            System.out.println("Initialization Successful. Your Jar Contains " + olives.size() + " Olives.");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: public static ArrayList<Olive> olives = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExceptionInitializerError`  is becuase you haven't initialized `olives`

add

```
olives = new ArrayList<Olive>();
```

before adding instances to list in static initializer block

Comment: Could you tell me why, if I do not set the member class as static, an error appears saying I cannot call a non-static class in main?

Comment: because you cannot access non static fields from static field, non static are tied to object's state, where static is static

Comment: A static belongs to the class itself and a non-static belongs to each object that is generated from that class.

Answer (score 1):

initialize your array

```
public static ArrayList<Olive> olives=new ArrayList<Olive>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `public static ArrayList<Olive> olives;` to `public static ArrayList<Olive> olives = new ArrayList<>;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your nested class has a field `olives` that you never initialize, so you get an exception when calling `add`. Assign an object to it:

```
olives = new ArrayList<>();
```

Additionally, both public and static fields are usually poor design. It's not clear what you're doing here, but this pattern shouldn't be used in real code.

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me why, if I do not set the member class as static, an error appears saying I cannot call a non-static class in main?